# Does on the fly creation of svg images via javascript make sense?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create an application that displays diagrams and allows the user to edit those diagrams.

Does it make sense to implement the editing of the way the svg-diagrams look in javascript or is it better to create all svg images at the server and send it from there to the user?

Are there any gotchers that I should think about when making that architecture decision?
Are there specific libraries that are good to use for editing svg diagrams live via javascript?

Comment: Have you looked into d3.js? It provides an API for svg creation and manipulation in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there specific libraries that are good to use for editing svg diagrams live via javascript?

Yes, there are several. But my favorite is Raphael.js because it's a proven cross browser vector library and it has a fairly clean API. Check out the demos on http://raphaeljs.com/.
Specifically, check out this demo: http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com no longer works, use this URL - http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/

Answer (score 0):

For scalability, I'd recommend doing this on the client side and figuring out a way to wrap your created presentation in a JSON object which you can send to the server on save for backup.

Comment: Sending a full object from the client back to the server for backup smells like a security risk. The client could put anything into the JSON object.